# solve integral $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\frac{sin(x)^2}{x^2 + a^2}} $

Tags: integration

How solve this integral? Perhaps by using deductions, but I don't understand how to do it.
$\displaystyle{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2 + a^2}}\mathrm{d}x} $

Comment: Contour integration seems like a good shot. Alternatively, you could take a limit of integrations-by-parts (probably)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hint, expanding on @FShrike's: this is an even function of $a$, which for $a>0$ (a condition you likely wanted to specify) can be evaluated with a semicircular contour in the upper half of the complex plane, using $\sin^2x=\frac12\Bbb R(1-e^{2ix})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using J.G. comment, we step into the complex plane, evaluating:

$$I(a) = \oint_{|z| = 1} \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{2}\Re\left(1 - e^{2iz}\right)}{(z-ia)(z+ia)}$$

Where the denominator has been factorized, and the numerator has been rewritten as J.G. suggested you. Now we just need to apply Residues Theorem.

$$I(a) = 2\pi i \text{Res}\left(f(z), z = ia\right)$$

thence

$$I(a) = 2\pi i \dfrac{1}{2} \lim_{z\to ia} \dfrac{\Re\left(1 - e^{2iz}\right)}{(z-ia)(z+ia)} = \dfrac{\pi}{a} \dfrac{1 - e^{-2a}}{2}$$

Now if you want, you can rewrite it by collecting $e^{-a}$ in the numerator:

$$I(a) = \dfrac{\pi}{a} e^{-a}\underbrace{\dfrac{(e^{a} -e^{-a})}{2}}_{=\sinh(a)}$$

Hence

$$\boxed{I(a) = \dfrac{\pi}{a}e^{-a} \sinh(a)}$$

Notice that in the special case $a = 0$ we get $I(0) = \pi$ as it should be (using the limit for $\sinh(a)/a$ as $a\to 0$):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \dfrac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}\ \text{d}x = \pi$$